# how to provide value for attribute If it is type of entity?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have `PERSON,ACCOUNT,PERSON_ACCOUNT`( for many to many relation of Person and Account) tables and entities.
Now `Account` having type like saving,corporate,salary..
this type are predefined values in `ACCOUNT_TYPE` table.(created table).

I have well define relationship.
small code for `Account` class

```
class Account{ 
private AccountType acctype;
}
```

now I want to create

```
                      Person p = new Person();
                      p.setFirstName();
                      p.setLastName();

                      Account account=new Account();
                      account.setAccountType() ? // how I get predefine value from database to here?

                  Set accounts; // other code to create set
                  p.setAccounts(accounts);
```

My question is how I write `account.setAccountType(accountTypeEntity.getAccountType())` ?
and it should not insert data into `ACCOUNT_TYPE` table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to query the database for the correct `AccountType` and then assign the value here.

When using JPA, all objects in Java must have corresponding entities in the database. You can't save or persist objects which have fields that the JPA mapper can't find somehow in the database.

So go to your session and run a query for the account type you want and assign the result.

Comment: sir data is already there like (saving,corporate,salary).. but How I give value to account.setAccountType( one of above? )

Comment: Show me the code that you would use to load an account type "saving" from the session manager.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a query to select the AccountType that you want to associate to the new account, and then do

```
account.setAccountType(objectYouGotFromQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on, where the enum/class AccountType is defined. If AccountType is enum, JPA automatically translates the enum to a varchar in DB.

```
public enum AccountType {
   SAVING, CORPORATE, SALARY
}
```

then you can use:

```
account.setAccountType(AccountType.SAVING);
//save the account to DB
```